# Autoload models, forms inside modules in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-autoloader

My application structure is like this:

- application

  - modules

    - default
    - student

      - controllers
      - forms

        - studentParent.php
      - models
      - views
      - Boostrap.php

I have a studentParent.php inside forms folder of student module.

```
class Student_Form_studentParent extends Zend_Dojo_Form{
}
```

Whenever I call this form class inside controller of student module, I get class not found error
I have placed Bootstrap.php inside student module.

```
class Student_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{

}
```

Here's my application.ini file configuration

```
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resource.modules=""
resources.view = ""
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
resources.layout.layout = "main_template"
```

My Bootstrap.php file:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
     protected function _initDefaultModuleAutoloader()
     {
         $moduleLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(
    array(
        "namespace" => '',
        "basePath"  => APPLICATION_PATH.'/modules/default'
        )
      );

          Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPrefix('App_Action_Helper');

          return $moduleLoader;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
resource.modules=""
```

should be:

```
resources.modules=""
```

(i.e. resources plural).

I would also recommend that you use an upper case letter to start your class names, so `Student_Form_StudentParent` instead of `Student_Form_studentParent` (the filename will need to be `StudentParent.php` as well). Personal preference I suppose, but if the framework does it one way and your app does it another then your class naming will not be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Also the

```
$moduleLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(
array(
    "namespace" => '',
    "basePath"  => APPLICATION_PATH.'/modules/default'
    )
  );
```

The **basePath** should point to the dir which contains modules, not, as in Your example, to the particular module dir.

Comment: Actually the module autoloader should point at the module dir, what he has is correct